# Disable Laravel 5 (not 5.1) middleware for testing

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5

Is there a way to turn off some Laravel 5.0 middleware for functional tests?

Comment: I'd say Laravel 5 includes Laravel 5.* . What version are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit `app/Http/kernel.php` file and comment any undesired middleware line in array `$middleware`.

You don't need to comment the ones in `$routeMiddleware` since these won't be automatically called, and they need to be specifically activated in the `routes.php` file.

**Another way:**

Copy `Kernel.php` as `Kerneltest.php` in the same folder.

Then rename the class in Kerneltest.php to `Kerneltest`and make it `extends Kernel`.

Then remove any middleware lines from Kerneltest

Then add the following to `bootstrap\app.php` :

```
$app->singleton(
    'Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kerneltest',
    'App\Http\Kerneltest'
);
```

Then in `public\index.php` use

```
$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kerneltest');
```

or

```
$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');
```

depending on whether you're testing or not.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. One more question, do you know approach to access kernel.php from inside test class?

Comment: Of course you *can't* "modify" the `kernel.php` file from any test class. What you can do, though, is move the appropiate middleware lines from $middleware to $routeMiddleware and then update your routes.php to use/avoid it depending on the route of your tests, as someone suggested here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes. Or you can modify the middleware classes themselves to avoid certain URIs. Plenty of examples on that page.

Comment: Can I write for example disableCsrf() method in a Kernel class (app/http/Kernel.php) and call it from test class? Or it's impossible, and the only way it's edit kernel.php manually every time?

Comment: May be there are some other sneaky way to resolve this situation. For example emulate _token key in request?

Answer (score 0):

I've found simple solution, although probably it may be not "TRUE", but it works. I've modified method handle() in my app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php to this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') === 'testing') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```